# Showing there exists a countable subfield $F\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ such that if $x\in F$, $\sin(x)\in F$

Tags: set-theory, transcendental-numbers

I am asked to show that there exists a countable subfield $F\subseteq\Bbb{R}$ such that if $x\in F$, $\sin(x)\in F$.

I don't see a classic set-theory approach to solving this. I started out by looking at $\frac{\pi}2\in F$ trying to build such $F$, which requires that $-\frac{\pi}2, 1, -1, \pi, 0, -\pi \in F$ following the definition for a field, but this is where I get lost. Clearly, $\sin (1)$ isn't "pretty" and I can't figure out how to count such a set. Should I start with an element and see how the field forms, or rather use set theory arguments more generally?

Comment: Maybe $sin(n)$ is a finite set ?

Comment: No, $\ \sin(n)\ $ is not a finite set. If $\ \sin(n) = \sin(m)\ $ for some $\ n,m\in\mathbb{Z},\ $ then $\ n = 2k\pi + m\ $ for some $\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\ $ which would imply that $\ \pi\ $ is rational, which we know is false.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Actually, it would be either $n = 2k\pi + m$ or $n = (2k+1)\pi - m$.  But again, the case $n = (2k+1)\pi - m$ would get a similar contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call $\Bbb Q(S)$ the smallest subfield of $\Bbb R$ that contains the set $S$. Proving that $\lvert \Bbb Q(S)\rvert=\max\{\lvert S\rvert,\aleph_0\}$ is an easy exercise. Call $H_0=\Bbb Q$ and define $H_{n+1}=\Bbb Q(H_n\cup\{\sin t\,:\, t\in H_n\})$. Then, $F=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}H_n$ is a subfield of $\Bbb R$ such that $\sin(x)\in F$ for all $x\in F$ and, in point of fact, it's the smallest such subfield. It is countable because it's countable union of countable sets. The specific function $\sin$ is not relevant; in point of fact, the same construction works for any function $f$, and in point of fact even for closure under application of functions from some countable family $\mathcal G$.

Comment: "Proving that $\lvert \Bbb Q(S)\rvert=\max\{\lvert S\rvert,\aleph_0\}$ is an easy exercise." I guess I'm stupid then... I just don't see it. In fact, I would like to see proof/ reasoning of this please.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $\ge$ is obvious by $\Bbb Q\cup S\subseteq\Bbb Q(S)$. On the other hand, this is the field of fractions of the ring $\Bbb Q[S]$ of polynomial expressions in $S$. Therefore there is a surjective function $\Bbb Q[S]\times\Bbb Q[S]\supseteq A\to\Bbb Q[S]$. Finally, there is a surjective map $\bigoplus_{v\in\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}S^n}\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q[S]$ given by sending each $n$-tuple $h\in S^n$ to $h_1\cdots h_n$. Since $\lvert\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}S^n\rvert=\max\{\lvert S\rvert,\aleph_0\}$, we have that $\dim_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb Q[S]\le \max\{\lvert S\rvert,\aleph_0\}$, and so is cardinality.

Comment: I need to study linear algebra... I bought a book but haven't got round to it yet...

Comment: @AdamRubinson It's basically a few iterations of the idea that for $\lvert D\rvert\ge\aleph_0$, if you fix a constant $a\in A$ and call $A^{\oplus D}=\{f\in A^D\,:\, f(x)=a\text{ for all but finitely many elements of }D\}$, then $A^{\oplus D}$ is union of $\lvert \mathcal P_f(D)\rvert=\lvert D\rvert$-many subsets of cardinality $\lvert A^m\rvert=\lvert A\rvert$, and therefore $\lvert A^{\oplus D}\rvert\le \max\{\lvert A\rvert,\lvert D\rvert\}$.

Comment: Yeah but for example, I don't even have much intuition of "direct sum". That's how long it's been since I studied linear algebra...

Comment: So, what this is based upon is that $\Bbb{Q}(H_0)=H_0$?

Comment: @Meitar $\Bbb Q(H_0)=H_0$ is true by the fact that $H_0=\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q(S)$ is what it is, but I don't see exactly how that's relevant.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why $||Q(S)|=\max\{|S|,\aleph_{0}\}$, because I don't get the surjective function from $\Bbb{Q}[S] \times \Bbb{Q}[S]$ to $\Bbb{Q}[S]$ and how it works. Why is this a fielf of fractions of polynomial expressions? How is that derived?

Comment: @Meitar Another way of arranging a similar proof might be: at each step, from $H_n$ form $H_n$ union the set of sums of elements of $H_n$, union the set of products of elements of $H_n$, union the set of negations of elements of $H_n$, union the set of multiplicative inverses of nonzero elements of $H_n$, union the set of sines of elements of $H_n$.  Then prove by induction on $n$ that each $H_n$ is countable, and the rest of the proof is similar to show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty H_n$ is countable, and is a subfield closed under $\sin$.

Comment: @Meitar There is a typo in my original comment. The surjection is from a subet $A\subseteq\Bbb Q[S]\times Bbb Q[S]$ onto $\Bbb Q(S)$ (not $\Bbb Q[S]$). Specifically, I'm referring to $(x,y)\to \frac{x}{y}$ and $A=\Bbb Q[S]\times (\Bbb Q[S]\setminus\{0\})$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of all formal expressions formed from integers via the field operations and application of $\sin$.  For example, $\frac{2 + \sin(3 + \sin(1))}{\sin(4 + 5)}$ could be one such formal expression.

Now, let us examine what happens when we try to evaluate such expressions.  Some of them might be invalid because they include a division by 0, for example in $\frac{1}{\sin(0)}$.  In other cases, we might get the same result from different expressions; for example, $\sin(4 + 5)$ and $\sin(9) + \sin(\sin(0))$ would give equal values.

However, what we *do* see is that if $E$ is the set of formal expressions, and $E'$ is the subset of expressions whose evaluation is valid, then we get a function $\operatorname{ev} : E' \to \mathbb{R}$.  Now, $E$ is countable (for example because every such expression can be encoded as an ASCII string that could be evaluated by some programming language, and the set of ASCII strings is countable; alternatively you could use an argument similar to the argument in the answer by Saucy O'Path, in showing that the set of formal expressions whose abstract syntax tree has depth $n$ is countable for each $n$).  Therefore, $E'$ is also countable, and so the image of $\operatorname{ev}$ is also a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The claim is now that $\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ which is closed under $\sin$.  The proof of this is straightforward; for example, if $x \in \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$, then by definition there exists some expression $e \in E'$ such that $\operatorname{ev}(e) = x$.  Then $\sin(e)$ forms another element of $E'$, and $\operatorname{ev}(\sin(e)) = \sin x$, so $\sin x \in \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$ also.  This shows that $\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$ is closed under $\sin$.  The proofs that $\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$ is also closed under addition, multiplication, negation, and under taking inverses of nonzero elements, will be similar.  And likewise, the proofs that $0, 1 \in \operatorname{im}(\operatorname{ev})$ are immediate.